# Adjacency matrix from Adjacency lists of a graph in matlab

Tags: matlab, graph-theory, adjacency-matrix, adjacency-list

I have  Adjacency lists of a graph with 198 vertices and 2472 edges. How can I construct adjacency matrix of graph?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Can you give more detail? Are your vertices a 198-by-2 matrix of coordinates? Are your edges a 2472-by-2 matrix of indices into your vertices?

Comment: You might read the documentation for `sparse` or `accumarray`

Answer (score 1):

Since you have 198 vertices, the adjacency matrix is 198 by 198, which is not so big. So we can just use a full matrix. Suppose the vertex number starts from 1. Suppose your adjacency lists matrix `AL` have the following format:

```
AL(1,:) = [1, 4, 6, -1, ...]
AL(2,:) = [2, 3, 7, 8, ...]
...
```

Where -1 is used to make the column of matrix `AL` same size.

Here is the code:

```
% initialize adjacency matrix
AM = zeros(198, 198)

% construct adjacency matrix 
L = length(A(1,:));
for i = 1:198
    for j = 1:L
        if AL(i,j) > 0
            AM(i,AL(i,j)) = 1;
        end
    end
end
```